# Is knockout.js ignoring disabled, or what could 'allow' <a> click on disabled element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, data-binding, knockout.js

I am working on a page that is using Jquery Mobile UI, knockout.js combination. There is validation mechanism that is supposed to disable JQuery mobile pagination if ViewModel is not Valid. I have checked and knockout mechanism is working fine, it is removing manually added `disabled ="disabled"` attribute when model switches state from invalid to valid. Problem is I am able to click on pagination control that is disabled (invoke knockout.js click binding javascript function call). I have even added `disabled ="disabled"` to all child controls.
 **Is knockout.js ignoring `disabled ="disabled"`, or is there different explanation?**

HTLM of Jquery mobile navigation control that can be clicked while being disabled below

```
<a data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-transition="none" data-bind="click: function() { onTheMove.loadPagingData(bcAccountProductAudit, 'GoToNextSet', true); }, enable : PageObj.isValid()" href="#" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-c" disabled="disabled">  
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" disabled="disabled">
        <span class="ui-btn-text" disabled="disabled"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow" disabled="disabled">&nbsp;</span> 
    </span>
</a>
```

IsValid false and control disabled

[image: IsValid false and control disabled]

Function inside on click got called

[image]

Stack trace where call originated

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout doesn't do any checking of its own to see if an element is disabled or not - the `click` binding just listens to the browser's click event for that element.

`disabled` is not a global attribute, so not all elements support it. If you had a `<button>` element with the `disabled` attribute set, and you clicked on that button, the browser wouldn't generate any click event that Knockout could listen to. The `<a>` tag does not support the `disabled` attribute however, so the browser will generate a click event regardless of whether you set that attribute or not.

The quickest way for you to fix this would be to either replace your `<a>` element with an element that supports the `disabled` attribute (e.g. `<button>`), or manually check if the element is disabled in your click handler. Note that while Knockout correctly removes the `disabled` attribute, it won't be able to add it again when the `enable` condition would evaluate to false for elements that don't support it - like `<a>` - so you'd probably have to check the actual condition instead.

Comment: For completeness sake, here's [a list of elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#concept-element-disabled) that are allowed to be disabled.